# Is there a way to check all label values of a dataset using pandas or numpy?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, machine-learning

I have a dataset with 4 features and 2 labels, 1 and 0.
Is there a way I can check all 1400 label values of that dataset and return which row it belongs to?
Columns 0-3 are features and column 4 is label value.

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

data = pd.read_csv('data_banknote_authentication.txt', header=None)

print(data.head())
print(data.tail())
print(data.info)
X = data.loc[:, :3]
Y = data[4]
```

Comment: `data[data[4]==0]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see all the 0 rows by:

```
data[data['4'] == 0]
```

and the 1s:

```
data[data['4'] == 1]
```